# SAP infoset query modify table after selection

Tags: sap-query

Is it possibly to modify certain rows of the output table in a SAP infoset query? If yes, how? I already tried writing some code for that in the coding tab in the infoset (at the end of selection - after the list) but I was not able to reference the table or fields.

Comment: You can do it only at infoset level. The best place is the event "Record processing" called for each line read. Do you want to change the values of some existing columns (easy the fields of the current line are names "table_or_view-column", for instance SFLIGHT-FLDATE and you can change them), or add new columns? Note: I think there are many blog posts around the web to answer your questions.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? SAP query is not the place for doing modifications